# How to create a RabbitMQ vhost when node is down

Tags: rabbitmq

I accidentally deleted the / vhost on a RabbitMQ node, and now it refuses to start. How do I recreate the / vhost? Running `sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost /` won't work because the node is down and won't boot.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? or did you just reset the db and start from scratch?